# That gap is a bit jarring

Tags: number-sequence

... but there doesn't seem to be anything missing.

> $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1527465$

What then could cause that rather large gap?

Comment: Is this a puzzle of your own creation?

Comment: @Hugh I came across the sequence more or less by accident, and was surprised that it wasn't on OEIS yet. I figured I'd post it here before adding it there :)

Comment: They're the solutions to the polynomial x^9 - 1527493x^8 + 42769342x^7 - 49185690x^6 + 2993838169x^5 - 10339423717x^4 + 20058670380x^3 - 5040x^2 + 7698423600x = 0, but for some reason I doubt that's the cause.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> The sequence 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 pointed towards octal numbers.
>  If we take the number 1527465 (base 10) and convert it to base 8 we get the same digits in reverse order 5647251
>  The gap is because no other number between 7 and 1527465 shares that property.

Comment: So, the sequence is: "numbers in base-10 that equal themselves backwards in base-8"? What could cause this gap?

Comment: @Hugh I've no clue yet. I'm still thinking (as  much as I can do any such thing)

Comment: @rhaquared That's alright; I have no idea either. For a start, any number containing an 8 or a 9 is out. Maybe it's worth brute force checking all the numbers up to 1527465 with a computer.

Comment: @Hugh see my edit

Comment: Don't overthink it :)

Comment: @Hugh just brute forced it all the way through 10,000,000 and you're right, these eight numbers are the only ones that reverse into their octal counterparts.

Comment: @snetch:  Note that any such numbers must be less than 10^10, since any 10-digit number in base 10 will have at least 11 digits in base 8.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I would hate to be working on the puzzle that required finding that out.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The 10-digit base 10 number 1073741823 is still only 10 digits when represented in base 8.

Comment: @jarnbjo:  You're right; I got mixed up between the exponent and the number of digits in the number.  I should have said:  "any such number must be less than 10^10, since any *11*-digit number in base 10 will have at least *12* digits in base 8."